# Does the sum of the outcomes of $n$ biased coin tosses equal any arbitrary integer $b$ at some point in time?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

Given the situation that we have a coin which has probability $p$ of landing on heads and probability $q=1-p$ of landing on tails, with $p>q$. Let $S_{n}=\sum_{n}^{i=1}X_{i}$, with $X_i$ the outcome of the $i^{th}$ coin toss.

This should be sufficient information (right?) to conclude that: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(S_{n})=\infty$. So we know the following:

$\forall M \geq 0: \exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n \geq N:S_{n} \geq M$

Can we conclude from this that for any arbitrary integer $b \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}:S_{N}=b$?

My guess is that we can, because we can't ''skip'' over any integers due to the way the outcomes of the coin tosses are set up. However, I'm not sure if any conclusions leading up to the final question are invalid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that $S_n$ is a random variable, so you need to use adequate notions of limits (like almost sure convergence). The statement of your question would probably look like do we have for any $b\in\mathbb N$, $\mathbb P\left[ \bigcup_{n\geq 0} \lbrace S_n = b\rbrace \right]=1$. The answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, you are right about the notation. I do have a question about your reply though. I am relatively new to this subject, but what is the actual meaning of: $\mathbb{P}[\cup_{n \geq 0} \{ S_{n}=b \} ]=1$? Does it mean that, when working in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, the probability of being in that set given an arbitrary $\omega$, is $1$? Sorry if what I'm saying is nonsense, I'm really trying to wrap my head around the statement.

Comment: When I asked about the meaning I meant what is the meaning in both the intuitive and mathematical way. I couldn't edit my comment anymore to add that.

Comment: When you are working with probability, $S_n :\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb N$ is a function that associate a value in the naturals to every outcome $\omega\in\Omega$, the event $\lbrace S_n = b \rbrace = \lbrace \omega \in\Omega \mid S_n(\omega) = b \rbrace $ is the set of all outcomes of $\Omega$ that are such that the given condition is respected, this event have a probability. A union of sets is just a or in the conditions and a or is also an $\exists$ statement. So the statement I mentioned is basically that $\exists n$ such that $S_n=b$ with probability 1.

Comment: Observe that this is different from having $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} \lbrace S_n =b\rbrace = \Omega$ since there is $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $\forall n$, $S_n(\omega)=0$, This is the one where all $X_i$ are $0$ for all $i$, but it have probability $0$ in the end, for proving your statement you should be carefull since there is also an infinity of such event, but I believe that the total probability of converging is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that clarification helps. So when we are talking about the set $\cup_{n \geq 0} \{ \omega \in \Omega : S_{n}(\omega)=b \}$, this is the set that contains all $\omega$ such that $S_{1}=b$ and all $\omega$ such that $S_{2}=b$ etc. However, it is still kind of unclear to me what it then means that ''the probability of this set equals 1''. Does it mean that for any arbitrary $\omega$, we are sure that this $\omega$ is in the set $\cup_{n \geq 0} \{ \omega \in \Omega : S_{n}(\omega)=b \}$? If so, why is that true?

Comment: No, this is my comment about the fact that this set is not necessarily $\Omega$, the thing is that the probability that $\omega$ is not in this set is $0$ which means that it will never happen in practice (but it could happen in theory) we say that $S_n=b$ for some $n$ almost surely.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now. Thanks alot for the effort!